Google Analytics Events Not Showing in Chrome Extension DebugView
I've developed a Chrome extension that modifies and saves recipes according to dietary preferences, with Google Analytics (GA4) integrated to track user interactions. Despite events being sent (verified via Chrome Developer Tools), no data appears in GA4 DebugView or Realtime reports.
This is the relevant part from the background.js file:
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener((message, sender, sendResponse) => {
    if (message.type === 'trackEvent') {
        sendAnalyticsEvent(message.category, message.action, message.label);
    }
});
function sendAnalyticsEvent(category, action, label) {
    chrome.storage.local.get('uniqueUserId', function(result) {
        const clientId = result.uniqueUserId || 'unknown_client';
        const trackingId = 'G-XXXXXXX';
        const url = `https://www.google-analytics.com/collect?v=1&t=event&tid=${trackingId}&cid=${clientId}&ec=${encodeURIComponent(category)}&ea=${encodeURIComponent(action)}&el=${encodeURIComponent(label)}&ds=debug`;

        fetch(url, { method: 'POST' })
          .then(response => {
              if (!response.ok) {
                  console.error('Failed to send event to Google Analytics');
              } else {
                  console.log('Event sent successfully');
              }
          })
          .catch(err => console.error('GA tracking failed', err));
    });
}


Steps Taken:

Verified GA4 Integration:
Confirmed correct tracking ID and event structure.
Ensured requests included ds=debug and received a 200 OK status.

2.Checked DebugView:
No events appeared in DebugView despite triggering multiple actions in the extension.

Browser & Extension Settings:
Disabled ad blockers, cleared cache, and checked for restrictive Chrome policies.
Reloaded the extension and tested in Incognito mode.

Need Help With:
Diagnosing why events aren't appearing in DebugView despite being sent.
Any potential issues in the extension's GA4 setup or event tracking code.
